# Finding Max sum of marks each year

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Scala and Spark, can someone optimize below Scala code for finding maximum marks scored by students each year

```
val m=sc.textFile("marks.csv")
val SumOfMarks=m.map(_.split(",")).mapPartitionsWithIndex {(idx, iter) => if (idx == 0) iter.drop(1) else iter}.map(l=>((l(0),l(1)),l(3).toInt)).reduceByKey(_+_).sortBy(line => (line._1._1, line._2), ascending=false)
var s:Int=0
var y:String="0"
for(i<-SumOfMarks){ if((i._1._1!=y) || (i._2==s && i._1._1==y)){ println(i);s=i._2;y=i._1._1}}


Input : marks.csv
year,student,sub,marks
2016,ram,maths,90
2016,ram,physics,86
2016,ram,chemistry,88
2016,raj,maths,84
2016,raj,physics,96
2016,raj,chemistry,98
2017,raghu,maths,96
2017,raghu,physics,98
2017,raghu,chemistry,94
2017,rajesh,maths,92
2017,rajesh,physics,98
2017,rajesh,chemistry,98
```

**Output :**

```
2017,raghu,288
2017,rajesh,288
2016,raj,278
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean exactly by "Optimised", but a more "scala-y" and "spark-y" way of doing this might be as follows:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

// Read your data file as a CSV file with row headers.
val marksDF = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("marks.csv")

// Calculate the total marks for each student in each year. The new total mark column will be called "totMark"
val marksByStudentYear = marksDF.groupBy(col("year"), col("student")).agg(sum(col("marks")).as("totMark"))

// Rank the marks within each year. Highest Mark will get rank 1, second highest rank 2 and so on.

// A benefit of rank is that if two scores have the same mark, they will both get the
// same rank.
val marksRankedByYear = marksByStudentYear.withColumn("rank", dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy("year").orderBy($"totMark".desc)))

// Finally filter so that we only have the "top scores" (rank = 1) for each year,
// order by year and student name and display the result.
val topStudents = marksRankedByYear.filter($"rank" === 1).orderBy($"year", $"student").show

topStudents.show
```

This will produce the following output in Spark-shell:

```
+----+-------+-------+----+
|year|student|totMark|rank|
+----+-------+-------+----+
|2016|    raj|  278.0|   1|
|2017|  raghu|  288.0|   1|
|2017| rajesh|  288.0|   1|
+----+-------+-------+----+
```

If you need a CSV displayed as per your question, you can use:

```scala
topStudents.collect.map(_.mkString(",")).foreach(println)
```

which produces:

```
2016,raj,278.0,1
2017,raghu,288.0,1
2017,rajesh,288.0,1
```

I have broken the process up into individual steps. This will allow you to see what is going on at each step by simply running show on an intermediate result. For example to see what the spark.read.option... does, simply enter marksDF.show into spark-shell

Since OP wanted an RDD version, here is one example. Probably it is not optimal, but it does give the correct result:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

// A Helper function which makes it slightly easier to view RDD content.
def dump[R] (rdd : RDD[R]) = rdd.collect.foreach(println)

val marksRdd = sc.textFile("marks.csv")
// A case class to annotate the content in the RDD
case class Report(year:Int, student:String, sub:String, mark:Int)

// Create the RDD as a series of Report objects - ignore the header.
val marksReportRdd = marksRdd.map(_.split(",")).mapPartitionsWithIndex {
    (idx, iter) => if (idx == 0) iter.drop(1) else iter
  }.map(r => Report(r(0).toInt,r(1),r(2),r(3).toInt))

// Group the data by year and student.
val marksGrouped = marksReportRdd.groupBy(report => (report.year, report.student))

// Calculate the total score for each student for each year by adding up the scores
// of each subject the student has taken in that year.
val totalMarkStudentYear = marksGrouped.map{ case (key, marks:Iterable[Report]) => (key, marks.foldLeft(0)((acc, rep) => acc + rep.mark))}

// Determine the highest score for each year.
val yearScoreHighest = totalMarkStudentYear.map{ case (key, score:Int) => (key._1, score) }.reduceByKey(math.max(_, _))

// Determine the list of students who have received the highest score in each year.
// This is achieved by joining the total marks each student received in each year
// to the highest score in each year.
// The join is performed on the key which must is a Tuple2(year, score).
// To achieve this, both RDD's must be mapped to produce this key with a data attribute.
// The data attribute for the highest scores is a dummy value "x".
// The data attribute for the student scores is the student's name.
val highestRankStudentByYear = totalMarkStudentYear.map{ case (key, score) => ((key._1, score), key._2)}.join (yearScoreHighest.map (k => (k, "x")))

// Finally extract the year, student name and score from the joined RDD
// Sort by year and name.
val result = highestRankStudentByYear.map{ case (key, score) => (key._1, score._1, key._2)}.sortBy( r => (r._1, r._2))

// Show the final result.
dump(result)


val result = highestRankStudentByYear.map{ case (key, score) => (key._1, score._1, key._2)}.sortBy( r => (r._1, r._2))

dump(result)
```

The result of the above is:

```
(2016,raj,278)
(2017,raghu,288)
(2017,rajesh,288)
```

As before, you can view the intermediate RDD's simply by dumping them using the dump function. NB: the dump function takes an RDD. If you want to show the content of a DataFrame or dataset use it's show method.

It is probably that there is a more optimal solution than the one above, but it does the job.

Hopefully the RDD version will encourage you to use DataFrames and/or DataSets if you can. Not only is the code simpler, but:

- Spark will evaluate DataFrames and DataSets and can optimise the overall transformation process. RDD's are not (i.e. they are executed one after another without optimisation). Translations DataFrame and DataSet based processes will likely run faster (assuming you don't manually optimise the RDD equivalent)
- DataSets and DataFrames allow schemas to varying degrees (e.g. named columns and data typing).
- DataFrames and DataSets can be queried using SQL.
- DataFrame and DataSet operations/methods are more aligned with SQL constructs
- DataFrames and DataSets are easier to use than RDD's
- DataSets (and RDD's) offer compile time error detection.
- DataSets are the future direction.

Check out these couple of links for more information:

https://data-flair.training/blogs/apache-spark-rdd-vs-dataframe-vs-dataset/
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/apache-spark-rdd-vs-dataframe-dataset-chandan-prakash/
https://medium.com/@sachee/apache-spark-dataframe-vs-rdd-24a04d2eb1b9

or simply google "spark should i use rdd or dataframe"

All the best with your project.

Comment: Thanks, This works fine. But I am looking for Non-DF solution. I think the code which I wrote is Simple Brute force one, and I guess it can be improved.

Comment: Dataframes add a lot of capability to Spark. May I ask why you would opt to not use them???

Comment: I am exploring the ways to implement Oracle Analytical/Window functions in Spark-Scala, without using Dataframes. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an RDD version. I hope you reconsider using DataFrames / DataSets over RDD's. A quick google search of "spark should i use rdd or dataframe" reveals lots of results - many, if not all, will recommend using Dataframes as a general rule.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer and Advise. I will try to use DataFrames where ever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try It on SCALA spark-shell

```
scala> val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("/CSV file location/marks.csv")
scala> df.registerTempTable("record")
scala> sql(" select year, student, marks from (select year, student, marks, RANK() over (partition by year order by marks desc) rank From ( Select year, student, SUM(marks) as marks from record group by Year, student)) where rank =1 ").show
```

It will generate the following table

```
+----+-------+-----+
|year|student|marks|
+----+-------+-----+
|2016|    raj|278.0|
|2017|  raghu|288.0|
|2017| rajesh|288.0|
+----+-------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions
//Finding Max sum of marks each year
object Marks2 {
  def getSparkContext() = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MaxMarksEachYear").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    sc
  }

  def dump[R](rdd: RDD[R]) = rdd.collect.foreach(println)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
   // System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "D:\\Setup\\hadoop_home")
    val sc = getSparkContext()

    val inpRDD = sc.textFile("marks.csv")
    val head = inpRDD.first()
    val marksRdd = inpRDD.filter(record=> !record.equals(head)).map(rec => rec.split(","))
    val marksByNameyear = marksRdd.map(rec =>((rec(0).toInt,rec(1)),rec(3).toInt))
    
    //marksByNameyear.cache()

    val aggMarksByYearName = marksByNameyear.reduceByKey(_+_)
    val maxMarksByYear = aggMarksByYearName.map(s=> (s._1._1,s._2))reduceByKey(math.max(_, _))
    
    
    val markYearName = aggMarksByYearName.map(s => (s._2.toInt,s._1._2))
    val marksAndYear = maxMarksByYear.map(s => (s._2.toInt,s._1))
    
    val tt = sc.broadcast(marksAndYear.collect().toMap)
    marksAndYear.flatMap {case(key,value) => tt.value.get(key).map {other => (other,value, key)  } } 
    val yearMarksName = marksAndYear.leftOuterJoin(markYearName) 
    
    val result = yearMarksName.map(s =>(s._2._1,s._2._2,s._1)).sortBy(f=>f._3, true)
   
   //dump(markYearName);'
   dump(result)

  }
}
```

Comment: This solution is  working effeciently beacuse its using reduceByKey instead of groupByKey.